# Insert query pdo doesn't insert data in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a project and right now I am making a post system so registerd users can post comments on the website but if I try to inserts data with my insert query it doesn't insert data into the database. So if someone could help me with this problem.

```
    <head>
    <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<form action="" method="post">
    <strong>Bericht :</strong><input type="text" name="bericht"><br />
    <strong>Content :</strong><textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="content"></textarea><br />

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        CKEDITOR.replace('content',
            {
                width: 500,
                height: 250
            });
    </script>
    <p>* Required</p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php

include_once "db.php";
include "repeatForm.php";



if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($_POST['bericht'] == '' || $_POST['content'] == '') {
        $error = "Niet alle velden waren ingevuld";
        repeatForm($error, '', '');
    } else {
        $insert = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO pages (berichtNaam, paginaContent) VALUES (:berichtNaam, :content)");
        $insert->bindParam(":berichtNaam", $_POST['bericht'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert->bindParam(":content", $_POST['content'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert->execute();

        header("Location: http://127.0.0.1/nieuws/index.php");
        exit;
    }
}

?>
```

Here is the database connection:

```
    <?php

    try {
        $dbcon = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=register', 'root', '');
    $dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }   catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
    ?>

and here the repeatForm:

<?php
function repeatForm() {
    echo "
    <form method='post' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' />
     <input style='font-size: 2.5rem' type='text' name='cTitle' >
    <textarea  name='ed1' cols='50' rows='10' ></textarea>


    <script>

    CKEDITOR.replace('ed1',
            {
                toolbar:[
                    { name: 'document', items: [ 'Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates' ] },
                    { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
                    { name: 'editing', items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
                    { name: 'forms', items: [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
                    '/',
                    { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
                    { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language' ] },
                    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
                    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe' ] },
                    '/',
                    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
                    { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
                    { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks' ] },
                    { name: 'about', items: [ 'About' ] }
                ],
                width: 600,
                height: 200
            });


    </script>
    <input type='submit' Name='submit' value='Post'><input type='submit' name='cancel' value='cancel'>
    </form> ";
}


?>
```

I receive this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
>
> Hallo
>
> )' at line 1' in Z:\sites\nieuws\create.php:34 Stack trace: #0 Z:\sites\nieuws\create.php(34): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in Z:\sites\nieuws\create.php on line 34

Comment: you're missing `exit();` after your `header()`  for a start, what error are you getting?

Comment: I get the following error: 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '<p>Hallo</p> )' at line 1' in Z:\sites\nieuws\create.php:34 Stack trace: #0 Z:\sites\nieuws\create.php(34): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in Z:\sites\nieuws\create.php on line 34

Comment: it was the exit I was missing thx for the answer.

Comment: For the code in question it is impossible to produce an error like this. Thus you are running whatever else code.

Comment: **Show all your code** Also make sure its the code from the correct file i.e. `Z:\sites\nieuws\create.php `

Comment: The code up here is from Z:sites\nieuws\create.php

Comment: have you debugged what your `:content` is? your error only shows your `text` being added and it seems one or the other is `null`

Comment: Also show the code for `db.php` and `repeatForm.php` if that contains PHP

Comment: I did get a new error: Submit

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'' in Z:\sites\nieuws\create.php:33 Stack trace: #0 Z:\sites\nieuws\create.php(33): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in Z:\sites\nieuws\create.php on line 33

Comment: I changed some bit of the repeatForm and got a different error

Comment: Duplicate entries are not code-side faults, you're adding a row that your database throws an exception over due to your primary key set-up - your code works fine; you just need to add a check that checks if it already exists before inserting. (Your primary key seems to be the ID) so why not make your `ID` auto increment?

Comment: @RemcodeBaas or maybe you don't have "autoincrement" on the ID field.

Comment: thank you my problem is solved.

Comment: I probably made my database a little bit to quick

Comment: As you have set the errmode to exception, you should really be coding all PDO inside a TRY/CATCH block

Comment: Okay, thank you for the info